# Convertir un entero a decimales

Tags: python

Necesito ayuda con este codigo, quiero que me guarde valores de una lista pero esta vez con un 0 por delante. Por ejemplo, si tengo un 30 en  el indice de una lista, quiero convertirlo en 0,30. No se como resolverlo, agradeceria su ayuda.

```
intereses_convertidos = []
        for i in int_anual:
            intereses_convertidos.append(0.(i))
        print(intereses_convertidos)
```

Comment: Divide entre 100

Answer (score 0):

2 formas de hacer, como dije en mi comentario puedes hacerlo dividiendo entre  `100`

```py
intereses_convertidos = []
int_anual =[10,30,40]
for i in int_anual:
    intereses_convertidos.append(i/100)
print(intereses_convertidos)intereses_convertidos)
```

O de una forma simplificada

```py
 intereses_convertidos = [i/100 for i in int_anual]
```

**resultado**

```
[0.1, 0.3, 0.4]
```

La segunda forma seria guardarlo como string pero al leerlo y operar tendrás que convertirlo a float, por lo que creo que la mejor opción es la primera

```py
intereses_convertidos = []
int_anual =[10,30,40]
for i in int_anual:
    intereses_convertidos.append(f"0.{i}")
print(intereses_convertidos)
```

Forma reducida

```py
 intereses_convertidos = [f"0.{i}" for i in int_anual]
```

**resultado**

```
['0.10', '0.30', '0.40']
```

Esto es un string por lo que tendrás que convertirlo a float y por eso digo que la mejor forma es la primera